# Can all positive integers of the form $4n+1$ be expressed as the sum of two squares?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know all primes, $p\equiv 1{\pmod 4}$ are the sum of two squares https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares

I vaguely recall that all composite integers, $x\equiv 1{\pmod 4}$ can also be expressed as the sum of two squares (and in more than one way), but I can’t remember, or find, a proof.

It’s certainly true all the examples I’ve tried, but please will somebody point me to a simple proof?

**Update 10th August 2017**
I can agree, at a push, that the candidate duplicate does provide an answer to this question, but I fail to see that it’s reasonable to expect me to recognise
$$n = p_1.p_2.p_3 \cdots p_k.m^2$$
and
$$x\equiv 1{\pmod 4}$$
as having the same meaning, especially as it was not flagged when I entered the question.

However, my question has been fully answered, so it matters little.

**I apologise, both for posting and for forgetting such an elementary fact.**

Comment: How about $21$?

Comment: No, for example $77$.

Comment: Only those numbers whose prime decomposition has $4n+3$ primes occurring with even powers.

Comment: To generalize the previous two comments, any product of two distinct primes $\equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Thank you, everybody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An odd integer greater than $1$ is the sum of two squares if and only if every prime factor of the form $4k+3$ in the factorization occurs with a power with even exponent.

Since the product of two distinct prime numbers of the form $4k+3$ results in a number of the form $4k+1$, such a product is a counterexample.

Comment: $3^3\cdot 7^3$ is another counterexample.

Comment: I think it's the same counterexample.

Comment: No, it is not the product of two distinct primes. But, I admit , it is a product containing only two distinct primes.

Comment: OK, now I understood. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As it has been shown in comments, it is not true that every positive integer $\equiv 1\pmod 4$ is the sum of two squares. The theorem that you are looking for says:

> A positive, odd integer $n$ is the sum of two squares if and only if
>   every prime $p\mid n$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $4$ or has even
>   exponent in the factorization of $n$.

Comment: You can do even also... for any $n$, you just need if $p \mid n$ and $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, then the exponent of $p$ is even.